# Android gps loation doesn't update in an app restart

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I have written a App in android using Google Maps Api V2. It periodically send gps location to a server.

The problem is it works fine in an fresh install and it periodically updates gps coordinates, but when i restart the app it doesn't update my current location automatically.

here is my code

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

// Google Map
GoogleMap googleMap;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//testing from a real server:
private static final String LOC_UPDATE_URL = "http://pissu.com/webservices/addcurrentloc.php";

//JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

//---lat and long variables
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;


// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 15 * 1; // 15s
// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //update current loc
    locationManager = (LocationManager) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

    CurrentLocMAP();//to show current loc

    RegisterAlarmBroadcast();

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), 20000 , pendingIntent); //20s
}

private void RegisterAlarmBroadcast() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        // private static final String TAG = "Alarm Example Receiver";
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            new AttemptSendLoc().execute();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm time has been reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("sample") );
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("sample"),0 );
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}

private void UnregisterAlarmBroadcast()
{
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); 
    getBaseContext().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

}

private void CurrentLocMAP() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    googleMap = mf.getMap();

    if(googleMap != null){

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//use of location services by firstly defining location manager.
        String provider=lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

        if(provider==null){
            onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
        Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


        if (loc!=null){
            onLocationChanged(loc);
        }
    }     
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LatLng latlng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());// This methods gets the users current longitude and latitude.

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));//Moves the camera to users current longitude and latitude
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,(float) 16.6));//Animates camera and zooms to preferred state on the user's current location.
    //update();

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lati+ " , " + longi ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}



//--------------------------------------------------server send---------------
class AttemptSendLoc extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    boolean failure = false;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String lati = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String longi = String.valueOf(longitude);
        String username = "ncbkkk";


        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longi", longi));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lati", lati));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script 
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOC_UPDATE_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Post location attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("location Added!", json.toString());    
            }else{
                Log.d("location Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it still hitting your server, or is it not making any requests?  If it is hitting your server, is it sending a latitude and longitude at all?

Comment: it sends the same location every 20s to the server, it doesn't update the gps coordinates in ever 15s.

Comment: Are you moving enough to get a new location?  Network provider is not that accurate-  you may have to walk a few hundred meters to get far enough to be detected.

Comment: I tried doing that, but still it wont update!

Answer (score 0):

Move "requestLocationUpdates" and the scheduling and unscheduling of your alarm to onResume() and onPause() instead of onCreate() and onDestroy(). I think that will fix your problem. What I think is happening is onPause() is being called at which point the LocationManager stops sending updates but onResume is called instead of onCreate() and so you are not re-requesting updates.

Also, consider logging in onProviderEnabled and onStatusChanged so that you at least know when the status changes. Perhaps it is being turned off and you don't know it since you aren't logging that at all.

An unrelated comment: Don't hardcode strings that the user will see. Always use a String resource so that you can easily internationalize later. It is easier to do this right all the time than it is to audit your code later. The new tools in AST make this even easier.

Comment: I changed every thing as you said but the problem didn't go away. Here gps coordinates doesn't update but it periodically send the same gps location, which got at the begining over and over again.

Comment: May be there is something wrong with how I'm getting the current location or it's due to alarm manager. If there is an alternative to periodically update the server without using alarm manager ,pls let me know.